# remote turtlebot powerup?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using turtlebot from a remote site and would like to powerup the create without asking someone local to the machine to push the button.  I know that there is a powerup pin on the 25 pin connector, but driving that requires adding an arduino or other sort of I/O board.
Anyone have ideas on how to remotely (say, via ssh) turn on/off the create without adding another board?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11369/remote-turtlebot-powerup?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The create is designed to be able to auto power on given a serial pulse on RTS but this only works if the receiving serial side is powered. In the turtlebot_driver code you'll see a wake command that does this but it only works when the create is plugged/receiving external power. If you have the TurtleBot auto-docking you might be able to get it to work. But other than that you must pulse the power on pin using an external device.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1